Correlation for a Multitask learning regression model
I have calculated the correlation for a MTL model like this as given below, and I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not. This is how I calculated it: 0) Correlation is calculated for descriptors (x = 762) and targets (y = 3, which are y1, y2, and y3).
Calculated the correlation of x with x and removed highly intercorrelated features (429) by setting some threshold value, say 0.9
After removing the highly intercorrelated descriptors (429), the correlation of the remaining noncorrelated descriptors (333) with the targets is calculated.
Calculated the correlation between non-correlated descriptors (333) and each target. My query is whether to calculate the correlation between non-correlated descriptors with each target separately (like I have done) or with all the targets altogether.
